# Linear Continuum and Connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A linear continuum is a set having more than one element which has
i) lub property
ii) if $x<y$ then there exists $z$ such that $x<z<y$.
If there are only two elements, how is the second condition possible?

Comment: Did someone tell you that a linear continuum can have just two points? I'd advise you not to consider that person a reliable source of information.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis that "$x<y$ implies existence of another element $z$ such that $x<z<y$" easily implies that a linear continuum can not have finitely many elements.
actually if we don't assume that at least 2 elements exists then one point set wouldn't be that much interesting!